# Replacement: How do I determine what wiring harness goes with my headlight?

Tags: headlight, wiring, replace

I have a 2005 scion xB and am needing to replace the headlights and one of the wiring harnesses.

I have seen on places like amazon and other sites for OE head lights, but I cannot seem to find anything relating to the wiring harness needed for those lights.

My driver side headlight wire is snapped and needs to be replaced. I am no expert, but I figured I could just splice a new wire connector on the existing one without having to replace the entire wire.

The car is completely stock, but I don't have an owners manual. How can I determine what type of connector/wire I need to replace the damaged one?

Here is a link for the headlights that I am going to purchase.
[Headlights](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008G34RIY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repin the connector or most auto parts stores will sell a replacement harness connector that you can crimp or solder on.

[image]
ECH LS6235

The xB takes a 9003 bulb.

Comment: I like the Dorman parts better p/n 84790. They have a rubber boot.  The above style works but can corrode in areas were salt is used.